# Discrete Math Recurrence with Binary

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find the recurrence relation of binary sequence of a length $n$ with no block of three consecutive $0$'s.

I know binary sequences are $0$'s and $1$'s but I'm not sure how would the recurrence relation work as a length for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ be the number of binary strings of length n without 3 consecutive 0's.
$a_1=2^0=1$ (since strings of length 1 cannot have 3 consecutive 0's)
$a_2=2^2=4$ (since strings of length 2 cannot have 3 consecutive 0's)
$a_3=2^3-1=7$ (since only '000' is not valid)

For $n \ge 4$,
Let $s_n$ be any n-bit string without 3 consecutive 0's.
Let $b_n$ be the number of n-bit strings without 3 consecutive 0's that end in 1
Let $c_n$ be the number of n-bit strings without 3 consecutive 0's that end in 0

$a_n=b_n+c_n$

$b_n$ is the number of (n-1)-bit strings without 3 consecutive 0's that have a 1 appended at the end.
So, $b_n=a_{n-1}$

$c_n$ is the number of n-bit strings without 3 consecutive 0's that end in 0.
$c_n$ is the number of n-bit strings without 3 consecutive 0's that end in '10' or '100'.
$c_n$ is the number of (n-1)-bit strings without 3 consecutive 0's that end in '1'  + number of (n-2)-bit strings without 3 consecutive 0's that end in 1.
So, $c_n=b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}=a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}$
So, $a_n=a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$

Finally,
$a_1=1, a_2=4, a_3=7$ and for $n \ge4,\,\,\,  a_n=a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$